# Multiplying only diagonal elements of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

I'm dealing with the following problem:

Suppose that I gave a upper diagonal matrix A of the form:
$A= \begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12}&\dots &a_{1n}\\
0 & a_{22}&\dots &a_{2n} \\
\vdots & \vdots&\dots &\vdots\\
0 & 0&\dots &a_{nn} \end{bmatrix}$

And a matrix $A'$ that is $A$ with only the diagonal elements multiplied by values $u_1,u_2,\dots,u_n$, but the upper diagonal elements stay intact, that is:
$A' = \begin{bmatrix} u_1 a_{11} & a_{12}&\dots &a_{1n}\\
0 & u_2 a_{22}&\dots &a_{2n} \\
\vdots & \vdots&\dots &\vdots\\
0 & 0&\dots &u_n a_{nn} \end{bmatrix}$

How can I express $A'$ in terms of $A$?

Is there a way to express it in the form $A' =UA$? But then, what is the form of the matrix U?

Comment: $A' = \begin{bmatrix} u_{1} & 0&\dots &0\\
0 & u_{2}&\dots &0 \\
\vdots & \vdots&\dots &\vdots\\
0 & 0&\dots &u_{n} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & 0&\dots &0\\
0 & a_{22}&\dots &0 \\
\vdots & \vdots&\dots &\vdots\\
0 & 0&\dots &a_{nn} \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix} 0 & a_{12}&\dots &a_{1n}\\
0 & 0&\dots &a_{2n} \\
\vdots & \vdots&\dots &\vdots\\
0 & 0&\dots &0 \end{bmatrix}$. You got to isolate the diagonal elements and then multiply I guess.

Comment: Just calculate $U=A'A^{-1}$

Comment: How about 
$$\eqalign{
A' &= A + {\rm Diag}(u\!-\!1){\,\rm Diag}(A) \cr
U &= A'A^{-1} = I + {\rm Diag}(u\!-\!1){\,\rm Diag}(A)A^{-1} \cr
}$$

Comment: @Widawensen I need something that does not involve $A'$

Comment: @greg your solution is the closest to what I was thinking initially. Still, it is going to put me in trouble, since it is just part of a bigger problem. I think there is no smart way out of this problem

Comment: @ArthurT If you calculate $A'A^{-1}$  you'll receive exact and the only form of $U$. You can do symbolic calculations at Wolphram Alpha.

Comment: @ArthurT Anyway, the result is diag$(u_1,u_2,u_3)$ + some nilpotent matrix with more complicated entries.